# How can we automate browser based download window using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, download, slimerjs

i am stuck with the following scenario. the scenario is, in my web page i have some files and i need to download that one. When i click on download button it throws download window. And how to automate this thing. I am using CasperJS and SlimerJS....below is the html code

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a id="export_notebook_gist" href="#">Export Notebook to File</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can download this file without click on the button. You just should getting url and open then in new window

Comment: but on clicking download. browser throws download window right. Now how do i automate that thing

Comment: you can not download file from pop up window because this place not available for slimerJs

Comment: can you provide me the solution..as i am new to the casperJS

Comment: what type file you want download ?

Comment: Not any particular file i wanted, for example in [https://slimerjs.org/download.html] SlimerJS download, if i click on download it shows download window. Now hoe to manage it

Comment: You can not manage this window, You can only getting url and pass them in php or python for download file in your PC

Answer (score 0):

You can use casper's [download](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) function to download a resource from a target page. All you have to do is to find the resource url that is linked to the download button and pass it to the casper's download function.

here is an example

```
 //Download a PDF report
 casper.then(function() { 
    var fs  = require('fs'); 
    var dataurl = this.findElUrl('#_2a7a2a0a2a1a0a'); // This is a jQuery function that finds the PDF file's url.

    var file =  new Date().getTime() + '.pdf';
    var fileloc = apppath + 'reports/' + file;

    self.download(dataurl, fileloc); // will download PDF to the specified directory
});
```

And the function to find the PDF url is

```
casper.findElUrl = function(selector){
var test = this.evaluate(function(selector) {
    return $(selector).data('url');
},selector);
return test;
}
```

BTW, you have to inject jQuery to the target page using casper's client script as follows.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
pageSettings: {
    webSecurityEnabled: false,
    loadImages:  false,
    loadPlugins: false
},

clientScripts: ["./jquery.min.js"]
});
```

hopes this helps..

Comment: can i download gist files as well? or else the above solution is only for PDF files?

Comment: for this can you tell me how to download?